# NAV menu doesn't appear on top

Tags: html, css

How do i make my nav menu permanently on top? I have two nav menu's on a page - a main hamburger nav menu that clicks and pops up, and then an embedded page nav menu

I would like the hamburger nav menu to be permanently on top, but for some reason the embedded nav menu appears through.

Here is a codepen of the issue: https://codepen.io/TheGreatEscape/pen/ebYgGO
Here is a short youtube video if the issue:  https://youtu.be/sWzCLOzRJUQ

and the related CSS Code:

```
/*===== NAV BUTTONS ===*/

#menu-button{ display:none}
a { 
-webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
-o-transition: .3s all ease;
transition: .3s all ease;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
outline: none;
float:none;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0 }

.templateux-navbar { 
position: fixed; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%;
padding: 0; 
z-index: 99999;
}

.templateux-navbar .container-fluid { 
max-width: 100%;
}

.templateux-navbar .toggle-menu { 
z-index: 9999;
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu { 
top:35px;
float:none; 
clear:both;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block; 
position:absolute;
right:210px
}


.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul { 
position:relative;
float:right; 
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 18.5px;
right:178px; 
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li { 
display: block; 
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li a {
left:30px;
top:.5px; 
text-decoration: none; 
border-radius:0; border:none; 
line-height:40px; 
display:block; 
margin-right: 0px; 
font-size: 13px;
text-transform: uppercase; 
letter-spacing: .05em;
color: #1a1a1a; 
position: relative; 
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li a:before { 
content: ""; 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 6px; 
height: 3px;
width: 0;
left: 0px; 
background: #f70f4d;
-webkit-transition: .45s width ease;
-o-transition: .45s width ease; 
transition: .45s width ease;
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li a:hover:before { 
width: 100%;
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li a:hover { 
text-decoration: none; 
background-color: inherit; 
border:none; 
color:#1a1a1a;
font-weight:bold
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li h5 {
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none; 
background-color: inherit; 
left: 125px;
top: -8px; 
color:#1a1a1a; 
font-weight:bold; 
font-size: 13px; 
border-radius:0; 
border:none; 
line-height:40px; 
display: inline-block; 
width: 100%;  
letter-spacing: .1em; 
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li.active > a:before {
width: 100%;
}

.templateux-navbar .templateux-menu ul li:last-child a {
margin-right: 0;
}

/*===== BACKGROUND MENU FOR MENU BUTTON, GET IN TOUCH ===*/

.menu {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: -56px;
  top: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu span {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3.25px;
  width: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .7s ease;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.visible {
  opacity: .97;
}

.menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: .7s ease;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  right: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: .8s ease;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#navigation {
  background: #000000;
  font-family: 'Titling Gothic Bold';
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 0px;
  width: 100%;
   height: 450px;
  text-align:left; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the `z-index`. I fixed it by adding the class `hamburger` to your first `.templateux-navbar` element and then modified your CSS a bit. You can see the modified CSS below.

```
.templateux-navbar { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; 
    z-index: 9;
}
.templateux-navbar.hamburger {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Your code has this issue because you gave both the menus the same z-index so it means that the element that is defined next in the HTML will naturally get higher priority, which in your case is your second nav.

Making your hamburger menu have a higher z-index solves this issue.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i tried to correct the error using the code you've provided, yet it still persists. can you show it on codepen working?

Comment: with your solution i encounter a new problem. it appears in your latest codepen too. the problem is the background is not solid black and appears an off grey color when the nav menu is being hovered over. when there is no hover it is black as needed. we want it black all the time, do you happen to know how?

Comment: did you happen to see my comment? the problem is fixed, but a new problem happened where the nav menu is a grey instead of black color because it's not appearing on top? How do i make it solid black again?